# 404 Not Found! when trying to server_ip/filename

Tags: server, http-status-code-404, remote-access

I have uploaded a file to /var/www/html, which is the document root on my server, but when I go to a browser and type ip_to_server/filename I get a 404 not found erorr page?

Answer (score 0):

folder "www" is the root folder by default. Have you changed it?

If you place your file directly in "www" (www/yourfile) and go to "ip_to_server/filename" it should work.

If you have a folder "html" in "www" and place your file under "html" then you'll need to go to "ip_to_server/html/filename" to access it

Comment: I have placed it in html and typed, my server ip/html/sfc/testselect.php